# Laravel login with Facebook

Tags: laravel

Frequently got this error when trying to login with Facebook.

`Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://`

[image: Error image]

This is what I got.

Provider function:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('Facebook')->redirect();
}
```

Call back function:

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('Facebook')->user();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to fix this

First one is to create a virtual host (HTTPS)

The easy one is to disable `ENFORCE HTTPS` in your facebook app settings

APP -> Facebook login -> Client OAuth Settings

[image]

Comment: The button in disabled. It cannot be changed.

Comment: apparently it's required in recent versions, you will have to create a https virtual server